# PHP / MYSQL - Best way to store data for a page layout and content in a CMS

Tags: php, mysql, performance, content-management-system, organization

I´m developing a simple, but flexible content manager, and for the pages management i want to give the user the opportunity to organize the layout by dragging contents in the page, being able to make rows of content divided by two or three, just like a table.

The following image can illustrate what i have in mind:

[image]

The user can make a layout to have an static image in the left, and a text on the right, and at the bottom, he can place an image gallery showing the thumbnails.

Now, my question is about how to store and load the data in Mysql...

I have two Options:

**1) With serialized data for the layout:**

In the page´s table i can have a field that will store a serialized data for this layout, and then, i just need to unserialize and make a loop with this array to assemble the content.

The Array would be like that:

```
// Rows / divisions ...
$array[0]['q'] = 2;
$array[1]['q'] = 1;

// The content
$array[0]['c'][0]['t'] = 3;     // 't' = type (3 = image)
$array[0]['c'][0]['i'] = 124;   // 'i' = id to search for this data
$array[0]['c'][1]['t'] = 1;     // 't' = type (1 = text)
$array[0]['c'][1]['i'] = 2;     // Referencia ao ID do conteudo
$array[1]['c'][0]['t'] = 4;     // 't' = type (4 = image gallery)
$array[1]['c'][0]['i'] = 9;     // Referencia ao ID do conteudo
```

and the serialized data to store in DB:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"q";i:2;s:1:"c";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"t";i:3;s:1:"i";i:124;}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"t";i:1;s:1:"i";i:2;}}}i:1;a:2:{s:1:"q";i:1;s:1:"c";a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:1:"t";i:4;s:1:"i";i:9;}}}}
```

Or i have other option:

**2) All in database:**

Here i can make a table to store all the "component" links for the page, including the rows/divisions and than i can make a query to assemble the content;

The table would be something like that:

```
id -> component id
id_page -> page´s id
type -> component type, and 0 == row
value -> id reference to content or quantity of divisions for the rows
```

And the data would be stored like that:

```
id / id_page / type / value
1 / 1 / 0 / 2 --> the first row divided in two
2 / 1 / 3 / 124 --> the image
3 / 1 / 1 / 2 --> the text
4 / 1 / 4 / 9 --> the image gallery
```

So, what options do you guys would use to have a better performance or better management? Is this the best way to make what i want?

Sorry if i was not clear in some point.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

When you need data or configurations previously saved for some element, its better to have it denormalized in a key value table.

```
element_id | serialized_data
```

performance wise you only need to index element_id and you will have a 1row hit for each element_id with the data on it.